# Can you attempt to counter an "can't-be-countered" spell?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Can you cast a counterspell on a spell that can't be countered, or is it not a legal target...

Just wondering if you can [Frightful Delusion](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Frightful%20Delusion) something that can't be countered but still have the player discard.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes you can, since the targeting requirement for counter spells is just 'target spell' not 'target spell that can be countered'.

When the counterspell goes to resolve it will do as much as possible, so it won't counter the spell but any other effects it would have (like [Frightful Delusion](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Frightful%20Delusion)'s discard) will still happen.

Comment: Similarly, you can target a tapped creature with a "tap target creature".

Comment: This means you can still Deprive an Emrakul to trigger your Sphinx-Bone Wand for the kill! Huzzah!

Comment: @Gendolkari's example is thoroughly covered [here](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/21027/2880). In fact, this question could be considered a duplicate of the one answered at that link.